# Spring Boot with Cognito always shows login screen in postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I am trying to debug a spring boot application secured behind AWS cognito.
I have set up the user pools and app config according to these tutorials:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito
- https://www.czetsuyatech.com/2021/01/aws-generate-cognito-access-token.html
- https://betterjavacode.com/programming/example-of-spring-boot-application-authentication-with-aws-cognito

I am only interested in programmatic REST access, not spring mvc.
Demo Controller:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: xxxxxx
            clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: w3p-app-client
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_zcZ0Enk0d
            user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

And this works in a browser `localhost:8080/hello`. I get the cognito login page where I can sign in with a demo user created in the user pool. After that I get the text "Hello" in my browser as expected.

Now I wanted to setup a postman collection for testing my API:
[image: postman config]

"Get New Access Token" opens the cognito login where I can successfully sign in and obtain the token. However if I now try to acces my `/hello`, with inherited auth from the parent, I still get redirected to the cognito login every time, even though the token is sent along.

[image]

I have saved the collection and request, I have tried with and without bearer, enabled all options in cognito and whatnot. At this point I am out of ideas. Any hints would be appreciated. For some reason cognito does not redirect to my api as in the browser, but send the login page instead. It seems like any auth setting is completely ignored, same behavior with "no auth" selected.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an issue in your `SecurityConfiguration` (chapter 3.3 in the linked article). Can you share this file?

Comment: @ElmarBrauch Thanks for your comment. My SecurityConfig indeed does differ, because I do not require html templating, only programmatic REST access. I have attached the code, Could this be the issue?

Comment: I have tried several variations of the config, but it seems to always results in either only the login page showing, or no auth being required at all (then i get the api response, but even without any token)

Answer (score 2):

In your case your service is in the role of a resource server. In the context of OAuth2 a resource server is an application, which endpoints are secured via OAuth tokens.

The basic configuration to make this work would be:

Add the following dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_zcZ0Enk0d
```

Your resource server will use this property to validate the incoming `JWT` tokens.

This is all you need in order to secure all your endpoints.

If you need to add any custom security configuration here is an example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .mvcMatchers("/my-public-endpoint").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .build();
    }
}
```

You can find further information in the `spring-security` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html)

Here is also one [tutorial](https://blog.marcusjanke.de/spring-boot-2-3-oauth-2-jwt-security-using-amazon-cognito-d10e4e40ac05)

Comment: Additional security config you'll likely need is mapping Cognito roles to Spring authorities. You'll also probably need CORS configuration and maybe sessions (and CSRF protection) disabling. Tutorials there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your `SecurityConfiguration`. You defined everything for anyRequest. You can use antMatchers to define authentication only for some request based on URL-path. Or you can give free access with permitAll to limited URLs by path with antMatchers. Here is an example how antMatchers can be used and how you can deal with all remaining (anyRequest) URL-paths.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/needToken").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```